# How to get the original referrer url on success?

Tags: php

I have a code that its executed only on the head tag of the success page.  This code is to track if the buyer is coming from Comission Junction.

I need to set a variable to true if the original referrer comes from commission junction affiliate links which looks like this:

http://www.jdoqocy.com/click-1245-2342423?SID=TrackingTest

is there an easy way to do this?

I was thinking about referral url but I guess that variable changes each time you go from page to page: add to cart -> billing address -> shipping address -> payment -> overview -> success

My code is

```
    public function getCommissionJunctionUdo($orderId) {
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
            $udo = array();
            $udo['CID'] = 'XXXX';
            $udo['TYPE'] = 'XXXX';
            $udo['CURRENCY'] = 'USD';
            $udo['OID'] = $orderId;
            $udo['DISCOUNT'] = number_format(abs($order->discount_amount),2);

            $order_coupon_code = $order->coupon_code;
            if(!is_null($order_coupon_code) && !empty($order_coupon_code)) {
                $udo['COUPON'] = $order_coupon_code;
            }

            $udo['PRODUCTLIST'] = self::_getOrderProductsList($order);       

            if(referral url come from CJ) 
{
                $udo['FIRECJ'] = "TRUE";
            }
            else {
                $udo['FIRECJ'] = "FALSE";
            }

            $masterTmsUdo['CJ'] = $udo;
            $json_masterTmsUdo = json_encode($masterTmsUdo);

            return $json_masterTmsUdo;

        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can save the referrer in the user session.

So if you have some observer code before each page load, do

If (referer is CJ) set flag in the session.

Then, at the checkout, just check this flag.

Comment: can you please guide me in the right way to create the observer one each page load?

Comment: You can use say controller-action-predispatch